# Make JavaScript Display Title

Tags: javascript, html

I have a website that has a `<title>` tag that is something like this: `<title>Blog post name &rarr; Site.com</title>` and I want the first part of it to be displayed.

So I want only the `Blog post name` to be displayed. Here is what I did to display the whole title:

```
Text blah blah blah: <script>document.write(document.title);</script> blah blah blah.
```

Is there a way I can do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a split on the `document.title` to get the first part.

All other things can be left unchanged.

```
<script>document.write(document.title.split("\u2192")[0]);</script>
```

`\u2192` is the code for the `&raar;` character

Comment: I think that would change the blog post's title. And I want it to be so that the code could work dynamically on any post that I want to write.

Comment: How do get the title of the blog post? is there a variable having the value?

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to use `indexOf` and `substring`:

```
<script>document.write(document.title.substring(0, document.title.indexOf('&rarr')));</script>
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hyffd/).